# Bouncy Castle ECIES compressed format

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I am using the bouncy castle ECIES with AES in CBC mode provider to encrypt data:

```
Cipher iesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("ECIESWITHAES-CBC");
iesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] ciphertext = iesCipher.doFinal(plaintext);
```

This results in a ciphertext with the format:

```
0x04 || coordinate x || coordinate y || PKCS5 padded ciphertext || 20-byte HMAC-digest
```

The `0x04` indicates the uncompressed format, where the y coordinate is also stored. Using eg. secp256k1, this results in 32 byte unnecessary overhead.

Now I would like to use the compressed format with `0x02` and `0x03` prefixes.

Unfortunately, I didn't find a specification of the parameters to use to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by setting the `usePointCompression` flag in the BC `IESParameterSpec` to `true`.

[The point compression flag is false by default.](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/9385b0ebd277724b167fe1d1456e3c112112be1f/prov/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/jce/spec/IESParameterSpec.java#L63)

Unfortunately, this flag is not part of their [ECIESTest](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/21dcb3d9744c83dcf2ff8fcee06dbca7bfa4ef35/prov/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/test/ECIESTest.java), so I used their encryption mode configuration (derivation, encoding and initialization vectors) to try out the flag:

```
byte[] derivation = Hex.decode("202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f");
byte[] encoding = Hex.decode("303132333435363738393a3b3c3d3e3f");
byte[] nonce = Hex.decode("000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f");

Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("ECIESwithAES-CBC", "BC");
IESParameterSpec params = new IESParameterSpec(derivation, encoding, 128, 128, nonce, true);
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey, params);
byte[] ciphertext = c.doFinal(plaintext);
```

This results in the desired format:

```
0x02 || coordinate x || PKCS5 padded ciphertext || 20-byte HMAC-digest
0x03 || coordinate x || PKCS5 padded ciphertext || 20-byte HMAC-digest
```

Depending on the corresponding y-coordinate (positve/negative).

Comment: Why the output is always different for same string?